# Selecting the right nth-childs

Tags: css, math, css-selectors

easy question, since my math skills fails. I need to target the following numbers of elements by css in a container by a nth-child calculation:

6, 9, 21, 24, 36, 39, 51, 54, 66, 69 and so on

Starting at 6, 9, 21, 24 there are always gaps of 30 elements (6 -> 36 / 9 -> 39 / 21 -> 51/ 24 -> 54 / 36 -> 66)

Any way to target those elements via css (maybe one ore few rules of nth-childs?), since it is an infinite loop of article? So the number could increase in the future, but the grid system will stay the same.

Comment: Did my answer not work? I'm curious if I misunderstood what you're asking.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just thought it is possible to reward two answers as correct. Atm I prefer Michaels solution, since he is only using two rules. But you were faster, your answer works as well. I give you the check back, cause you were faster, thought, I can reward various answers

Comment: I think you have me and the other answerer confused. You initially chose the one with 4 rules (the other user, not me), but I answered with 2 rules. Since it seems like 2 rules is a better answer than 4, I assumed you would have chosen my answer, but you didn't. So I assumed I got it wrong or something... but then you switched the answers to choose mine as the solution, then reverted it back and gave the answer to the user who answered first. For what it's worth, you should choose the answer that is the "best solution" https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: You shouldn't just choose the answer that was first. That is a big problem on stack overflow - people rushing in to get the answer in first so they're chosen. There is a "fastest gun in the west" thread that talks about it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem The website isn't a race, it's about finding good solutions to problems. If someone answers tomorrow with a single rule, you should choose that as the solution since this question will live forever and the best solution to the problem should be the chosen solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with 2 rules.

```css
div:nth-child(15n + 6), div:nth-child(15n + 9) {
  color: red;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16</div>
<div>17</div>
<div>18</div>
<div>19</div>
<div>20</div>
<div>21</div>
<div>22</div>
<div>23</div>
<div>24</div>
<div>25</div>
<div>26</div>
<div>27</div>
<div>28</div>
<div>29</div>
<div>30</div>
<div>31</div>
<div>32</div>
<div>33</div>
<div>34</div>
<div>35</div>
<div>36</div>
<div>37</div>
<div>38</div>
<div>39</div>
<div>40</div>
<div>41</div>
<div>42</div>
<div>43</div>
<div>44</div>
<div>45</div>
<div>46</div>
<div>47</div>
<div>48</div>
<div>49</div>
<div>50</div>
<div>51</div>
<div>52</div>
<div>53</div>
<div>54</div>
<div>55</div>
<div>56</div>
<div>57</div>
<div>58</div>
<div>59</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need four separate `nth-child` rules, as follows:

```
nth-child(30n+6),
nth-child(30n+9),
nth-child(30n+21),
nth-child(30n+24)
{
//...
}
```

Comment: so easy, oh my god, yeah that made it, thank you ;) you'll get the right answer button in four minutes. Thank you so much :)

Comment: No worries :) glad to help.